Angular - dynamic HTML element Id
I have template:
<div
*ngFor="let row of rows"
title="{{ row.text }}"
<span
    [id]="tag.index" + {{ implementor }}
    tabIndex="0">
    {{ row.text }}
</span>

Something like this works with no problem:
[id]="tag.index"

Since I am implementing this template in a few places on the same screen
I need to make id unique. The code above compiles, but the runtime gives this error:
Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '+' is not a valid attribute name.

Any idea how to make it work?
Thanks

You don't have a < bracket for the div, even in the real code?, or is it a copying error?

use either id="{{tag.index}}_text_{{anoOtherValue}}" or [id]="tag.index+"_text_"+anoOtherValue". _text_ here is just an example of how to add a simple string

Copy and paste. @ Andrei Will try your code right away.

[id]="tag.index+"text"+anoOtherValue" is not compiling. Error:  Opening tag "span" not terminated. First example is not compiling either. Same error.

Actually this compiles: id="{{tag.index}}_{{implementor}}". Runtime error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'index')

try row.index. it is a reference to the value. I though you have it but it seems you don't

Yes, row.index. Lookes like this id="{{tag.index}}text{{anoOtherValue}}" is working. everyone thanks for the help.
